# Rsync, не работает исключение директорий

Tags: linux

Использую `rsync` так:

```
rsync -avz --exclude=node_modules --exclude=.git --delete --force . /TestDir/
```

Все работает корректоно.

```
rsync -avz --exclude={"node_modules",".git"} --delete --force . /TestDir/
```

И тут исключение не работает, node modules копируются.

Comment: пробел после запятой лишний...

Comment: Пробел убрал, но все равно не работает.

Comment: Фигурные скобки обрабатывает интерпретатор команд. Какой он у вас? bash?

Comment: sh. А экранировать можно?

Comment: sh не поддерживает такой синтаксис, поэтому и не работает, поставьте bash

Comment: Понял, спасибо, добавьте, пожалуйста, в ответ, - закрою.